# Woocommerce simple filter php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My php skills is very low. I need some help this this function. 
What it should do: When a order is marked as "failed" it should redirect to the woocommerce cart with an error message.

But problem is that this code redirect ALL status to the cart with the error message (even if payment is approved).

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', function(){



global $woocommerce;
$order = new WC_Order();
if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) {
wp_redirect( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() );  // or whatever url you want
wc_add_notice ( __( 'Payment Failed', 'woocommerce' ), 'error');
exit;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are cheching if status IS NOT `failed` and then redirect.

Change

```
if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) {
```

to

```
if ( $order->get_status() == 'failed' ) {
```

See [PHP comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Also, you are not getting correct order. Your function should take `$order_id` and load correct order.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', function( $order_id ){
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
  if ( $order->get_status() == 'failed' ) {
    wp_redirect( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() );  // or whatever url you want
    wc_add_notice ( __( 'Payment Failed', 'woocommerce' ), 'error');
    exit;
  }
}, 10, 1);
```

Comment: i have tried that too but then it ignores everything

Comment: nope, that's not work either. i have also tried has_order with no luck.

Comment: Check if you get correct `$order_id` and `$order`. If yes, check what `$order->get_status()` gives you. Just print it.

Comment: I dont know how to do that, like i said iam low skilled php user

Comment: `print_r($order_id);` and `print_r($order->get_status());` after you create `$order` object.

Comment: Iam really sorry but i do not understand how to do that. in what file should i put that code?

Comment: In this same hook after line of $order

Comment: yes i got the right output on both order id(309) and status(failed) . but still ignores  my redirect

Comment: There was some problem with the redirect code.
Changed wp_redirect( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() ); to wp_redirect(".home_url('cart')."); 
And now it is working, thank you Rene!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use the hook "woocommerce_order_status_failed" instead of "woocommerce_thankyou" as it will trigger only when the order status is failed.
Secondly you need to pass the order id in the function new WC_Order() so that it will get the details of that order. and then you can use the if statement to check if the order status if failed or not. You are using wrong operator "!=" in the if statement, so it is going to cart page for All status except failed one. You should use the "==" operator so that if the order status is equal to failed only then the statement will processed. The function you are using to get url is not compatible with new version of woocommerce, However you can use get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ) function to get the url of cart page.

Here is an example :

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed', 'mysite_failed');

function mysite_failed($order_id) {

```
 $url = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) );
 $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
 if ( $order->get_status() == 'failed' ) {
 wp_redirect($url);
 wp_redirect( $woocommerce->cart->wc_get_cart_url() ); // or whatever url you want
 wc_add_notice ( __( 'Payment Failed', 'woocommerce' ), 'error');

exit;
```

}
}